# Too many connection to Postgresql in java

Tags: java, postgresql, performance, database-connection

I use postgresql for DB and have a connection problem. The project is very big, with a lot of inner flows, and very complex... Sometimes, the app creates a lot of connections, and there are no connections left in the db, and the app freezes. The problem is not in the db, it is in the app.

When I look into `pg_stat_activity`, i see all the connections, and their query is `select 1` (the first query that occures when connection is open, to validate the connection). So it seems that the app opens a connection, and does not use it. And when there are to many of those... you know...

I dont know where from, in the code, the connection open.

Is there a technic/tool for java/postgres to know where they come from?

From just looking at the code it will take forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature in PostgreSQL to find something in the application source directly.

You could only try enable to more detailed logging on PostgreSQL side with the right  `log_line_prefix` and `log_statement` parameter: this could only help if the statements are submitted from a specific executable or host (because related logged data could help finding the right code section).

If application starts a transaction that stays idle too long, you can set `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`.

Unfortunately PostgreSQL has no timeout for idle sessions that are not running a transaction.